# Two successive BLOCs in flutter_bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I want to split my BLOC into two BLOCs:

1. the one who does preparing job
2. the main one

Let's call it PrepBloc and MainBloc. Is it reasonable way to put one inside another like this:

```
BlocProvider<PrepBloc>(
          create: ......,
          child: AppView()
        )
class AppView extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<PrepBloc, PrepState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is ReadyState) {
          return BlocProvider<MainBloc>(...);
        }
        else if (state is NotReadyState) {
          return PrepPage();
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I know there is MultiBloc thing but it seems to me a little sophisticated and producing a lots of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is absolutley a correct way to do it!

You would use a MultiBlocProvider if the children need access to both blocs, but in your case that isn't what you are after. I guess there is no point for PrepPage to have access to MainBloc.

Comment: Thank you, Robert! (PrepPage/Bloc is just some stuff about login etc)

Comment: Great. You can see how it makes sense if you'd for the ready state return a widget that you might have defined in a separate file. If you in that widget would start with a BlocProvider then it doesn't feel as peculiar nesting blocs. You could also consider them as StatefulWidget's, and those you nest without any question  Accept the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.

Comment: It's a great compehensive answer. I'm new on site and haven't noticed this button about accepting.